# What do you call a very flexible rod?

Tags: cabling

At work, the guy next to me goes to sites and does cable installs. He is having an issue with one site where there is a 90 degree bend and a traditional rod is not flexible enough.

He has been trying to source a tool for a while that he has used on a previous job that he thinks is called a "jimmy", which is very flexible and runs from a pump, but, after ringing around a few suppliers, we are unable to source the correct tool.

I was wondering if anyone knows what this is called or can anyone recommend any other tool for the job?

Answer (score 9):

Your friend is looking for Fish Tape, like [this](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=fishing%20tape&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=11173114277192652385&sa=X&ei=6P3lTq6WGouEtgfC4oTOBA&ved=0CJ0BEPMCMAQ)

[image]

or like [this](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=fishing%20tape&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=9286276841989977259&sa=X&ei=6P3lTq6WGouEtgfC4oTOBA&ved=0CI8BEPMCMAE).

[image]